# How to setup an Artifactory cluster with a Percona cluster?

Tags: artifactory, percona

I am trying to setup an Artifactory cluster (one master and one slave) with a Percona mysql cluster but I am failing to understand how this works.

I have installed 2 Artifactory instances on 2 nodes which are using the same database cluster. The idea is to have different configurations (http proxy, reverse proxy, base URL etc..). I am using this tutorial https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Clustering+Artifactory. But as soon as I restart Artifactory, both the nodes have the same configurations. Is this how it's supposed to work?

Is there a way to setup this installation with having different configurations for http proxy, reverse proxy and base url but with the same config for repos (local, remote dhe virtual)?

edit: installations should be synchronized with each other. If I add a binary on Artifactory1, it should be replicated to Artifactory2.

Thank you

Comment: Seems like what you're looking for isn't a cluster but a Replication of two separate instances. check this out: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Repository+Replication

Comment: Percona MySQL Cluster is not master/slave; it is a cluster (ie: synchronous writes); yes, there is a distinct difference. So, do you have Percona XtraDB Cluster or do you have master/slave? In either case, the data for your application will be the same across both nodes; that's the whole point. Yes, you can have different proxy/base-url/etc (that is all front-end tech) and still have the app configuration and use the same back-end database. Cannot really tell if this is an issue related to MySQL or with Artifactory.